# Install & update package on Debian without internet

Tags: linux, debian

There is computer with Debian, but no internet connection at one place and computer with Windows 7/Arch Linux at other place (my home) with internet connection. Is there a way to update and install software on Debian? E. g. get list of packages on Debian, download them at home computer, install on Debian. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [apt-zip](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/apt-zip) package.

> **Update a non-networked computer using apt and removable media**
>
> These scripts simplify the process of using dselect and apt on a non-networked Debian box, using removable media like ZIP floppies and USB keys.
>
> One generates a `fetch' script (supporting backends such as wget and lftp, in a modular, extensible way) to be run on a host with better connectivity, check space constraints of your removable media, and then install the package on your Debian box.

Comment: Can you expand your answer a bit, maybe explain how to use it?

Comment: I haven't actually used it, I just know of it.